# CodeIgniter loading doctypes config

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I try to load the application/config/doctype.php config file in codeigniter
it gives me the next error

```
Your application/config/doctypes.php file does not appear to contain a valid configuration array.
```

My code is (taken from an example at CI docs)

```
$this->config->load('doctypes', FALSE, TRUE);
$x = $this->config->item('html5','doctypes');
echo "<pre>";var_dump($x);die;//
```

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to system/helpers/html_helper.php, you can juste use :

```
include(APPPATH.'config/doctypes.php');
```

And if you want to understand, look in Config.php core file, row 132 :

```
include($file_path);
if ( ! isset($config) OR ! is_array($config))
{
    if ($fail_gracefully === TRUE)
    {
         return FALSE;
    }
    show_error('Your '.$file_path.' file does not appear to contain a valid configuration array.');
}
```

If you use $this->load->config($file), you must have a $config variable in your file.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to load the HTML helper in your controller:

```
$this->load->helper('html');
```

Once loaded, one can access the doctypes like so:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
    <?=doctype('html5');?>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    ...
```

From the documentation: http://www-scf.usc.edu/~adportno/apache/htdocs/adportno/hw5/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html#doctype